# FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation and requestLocationUpdates take very long time to return

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

I face todays a problem with a fresh mobile. when i do :

```
mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest.setInterval(150000);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(30000);
mLocationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(900000);
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(25);

Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient); 
if (location == null) { Log.w(TAG, "getLastLocation return null"); }
else { onLocationChanged(location); }

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

The problem is that `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` return null. normally this is not a big problem as we also setup `requestLocationUpdates`. BUT the problem is that requestLocationUpdates take a very long time to return. How can i say to `requestLocationUpdates` to return the fastest as possible the First location, and to return the following location at interval like we configured the `mLocationRequest` ?

Answer (score 2):

You should create 2 different location requests, the one you have for regular location updates, and also one like this for getting current location fast:

```
mLocationRequest2 = new LocationRequest();
mLocationRequest2.setInterval(500);
mLocationRequest2.setFastestInterval(0);
mLocationRequest2.setMaxWaitTime(1000);
mLocationRequest2.setNumUpdates(1);
mLocationRequest2.setPriority(LocationRequest.HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

The `setNumUpdates` will make sure this LocationRequest will be called only once.

Comment: so i can do at the same time 2 requests like LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this); immediatly followed by LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest2, this); ?

Comment: Mmm.. I need to re-read the docs, but I don't think you can.. I think you need to switch between them when it suits your purpose. The separation is only for convenient.